# C++ Vector iteration failing for single element input

Tags: c++, parsing, text, vector

I am trying to get a txt file with entries part1/1 part2/4 etc... from user and store in vectors "part_name" and "rev_id". So "part_name" contains part1 part2 ... and "rev_id" contains 1 4.....
The program is run as program.exe list.txt in command prompt.

The program works fine when the txt file has 2 or more inputs , but when it has single input the `vector` size is shown as 2 (but must be 1).
i.e.

if `list.txt` contains `part1`/`1` `part2`/`4` `=> part_name.size()` is 2

if `list.txt` contains `part1`/`1`  `=> part_name.size()` is still 2.

Can someone help me resolve this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

std::string s ;
std::string delimiter = "/";
size_t pos;
std::vector<std::string> part_name;
std::vector<std::string> rev_id;
std::string token1,token2;


ifstream readFile (argv[1]);
if (readFile.is_open()) 
{
 while (!readFile.eof()) 
{
    readFile >> s;
    pos=s.find(delimiter);
    if((pos!=std::string::npos)&&(pos!=0))
    {

    token1 = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
    token2 = s.substr(pos + delimiter.length());

    part_name.push_back(token1);
    rev_id.push_back(token2);
    }
 }
}
else{

   std::cout<<"Cannot open file"<<endl;
}
readFile.close();

  for (unsigned j=0; j < part_name.size(); j++)
 {
    cout<<part_name.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"part name j is " <<part_name[j]<<endl;
    cout<<"part id j is " <<rev_id[j]<<endl;
 }


}
```

Comment: Is `part1/1` one its own line or can there be multiple "parts" per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies here

```
while (!readFile.eof()) 
{
readFile >> s;
pos=s.find(delimiter);
if((pos!=std::string::npos)&&(pos!=0))
{

token1 = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
token2 = s.substr(pos + delimiter.length());

part_name.push_back(token1);
rev_id.push_back(token2);
}
```

change above to

```
 while (readFile >> s) 
{

pos=s.find(delimiter);
if((pos!=std::string::npos)&&(pos!=0))
{

token1 = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
token2 = s.substr(pos + delimiter.length());

part_name.push_back(token1);
rev_id.push_back(token2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay ,Thanks George

Answer (score 1):

Your last read is probably not reading anything.  Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    std::string s ;
    std::string delimiter = "/";
    size_t pos;
    std::vector<std::string> part_name;
    std::vector<std::string> rev_id;
    std::string token1,token2;

    ifstream readFile (argv[1]);
    if (readFile.is_open()) 
    {
        while( ( readFile >> s ).good() )
        {
            std::cerr << "Field '" << s << "'  and " << readFile.good() << std::endl;
            pos=s.find(delimiter);
            if((pos!=std::string::npos)&&(pos!=0))
            {
                token1 = s.substr(0, pos);
                token2 = s.substr(pos + delimiter.length());
                part_name.push_back(token1);
                rev_id.push_back(token2);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout<<"Cannot open file"<<endl;
    }
    readFile.close();

    for (unsigned j=0; j < part_name.size(); j++)
    {
        cout<<part_name.size()<<endl;
        cout<<"part name j is " <<part_name[j]<<endl;
        cout<<"part id j is " <<rev_id[j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`eof()` returns true not when the file position is at the end, but after you attempt a read at the end of the file. So the first time in the loop you consume the input up to the eof (not included). Now `eof()` is false. For this reason the loop is entered again and this time the extractor (>>) hits the end of file. The read operation fails and the string is not changed (that's why you see the same values twice).

A better (and more idiomatic to modern C++) way to code is by using stream iterators

```
#include <iterator>

// [...]

std::istream_iterator<std::string> scan( readFile );
std::istream_iteartor<std::string> eof;
while( scan != eof )
{
    s = *scan++;
    // s is your string
}
```

Also it would be better to have the loop in the second part to run from 0 upward, since elements in vectors are numbered starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are some lines than make me suspicious..
Why start your iteration loop by the index 1 ?

```
  for (unsigned j=1; j < part_name.size(); j++)
 {
    cout<<part_name.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"part name j is " <<part_name[j]<<endl;
    cout<<"part id j is " <<rev_id[j]<<endl;
 }
```

You always skip the first element of yours vectors.

Comment: Hi Alexis , that was a typo , i did correct it (j=0) , but the problem still exist ...